# React-native is not recognizing a component as a component

Tags: react-native, components, react-navigation

I have an react-native app, using react-navigation.

I have used an example, that works perfectly, but when I add my own component I get an error message, that it's not a component.

Error message:

> "The component for route Loginscreen must be a react component"

Code for component that works:

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component { render() {
   return ( <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Details Screen</Text>
  </View>);}}
```

Code for component that don't work:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
    <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/Background.png')} style={styles.background}>
  </ImageBackground>
);}
```

I ofcourse have the imports, and I've done this:

```
export default createStackNavigator({   
   Home: { screen: HomeScreen, },
   Details: { screen: DetailsScreen,},
   LoginScreen: { screen: Login,},},
{ initialRouteName: 'Login',});
```

I'm completely confused, as there are no functional differences, and the docuimentation does not reference this, nor can I find similar issues

thank you for your time reading this

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @ArielSalem "The component for route Loginscreen must be a react component"

Comment: How're you exporting your Login component and how are you importing your Login component into the navigator?

Comment: @ArielSalem I discovered the answer by accident. turns out that the "screens" have to be before the "export default createStackNavigator", and I had it in the middle of my components. Thank you for taking the time to help me

Comment: no problem, glad you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!

I was trying to test this myself to fix it, and suddenly it worked. Looking at the edit history I discovered that I had moved my "export default createStackNavigator", to the bottom from the middel of app.js.

I'm a .net dev, so this was not intuitive based on my experiences